# Fortran Final Procedures Not Being Called in the Expected Manner

Tags: fortran, destructor, finalize

I have a container type that has an allocatable array of another type. When the final procedure is called on the container type and the allocatable array is deallocated, it doesn't trigger the final procedure on each individual object in the array which is what I would expect. Below is some example code demonstrating my problem.

```
Module AType
implicit none

Type A_T
    real :: x
End Type A_T

Type Inner_T
    Class(A_T), allocatable :: A
contains
    final :: inner_destroy
End Type Inner_T

Type Container_T
    type(Inner_T), dimension(:), allocatable :: inners
contains
    final :: container_destroy
End Type Container_T
  
contains

subroutine inner_destroy(this)
    type(Inner_T), intent(inout) :: this
    if(allocated(this%A)) deallocate(this%A)
end subroutine inner_destroy

subroutine container_destroy(this)
    type(Container_T), intent(inout) :: this
    if(allocated(this%inners)) deallocate(this%inners)
end subroutine container_destroy

End Module AType
```

While the container final method is called upon `Container_T` moving out of scope, the final method of `Inner_T` is not called from the deallocation of the containing array. Is there is convenient way to trigger this final method or do I have to create a wrapper type for `Inner_T`? Or is this incorrect behavior?

Comment: The component `inners` is an array, but you haven't provided a final subroutine for an array of type `Inner_T`, or an elemental final subroutine for a scalar of type `Inner_T`.  You can find details of that in the linked question and its answers.

Comment: perfect, thank you.